# Can't seem to split a string in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a string at its commas in Python at the moment and I'm getting the error `main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`
This is what I have as of right now.

```
def main(self):
    last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan')

def last_letters(self):
    last_letters1 = last_letters.split(",")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:
After I remove `self` from the def, I am still left with this error--

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/main.py", line 2, in main
    last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan')
TypeError: last_letters() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

`

Comment: is that in a class?

Comment: @TenaciousB no it isn't

Comment: You only need `self` when your function is a method of a class.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare that a function takes a positional argument, then you must supply that argument when calling the function.

As it is, your `main()` function does not require any argument so just change it to:

```
def main():
    last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan')
```

Also, the argument name `self` is by convention used as a reference to an object instance within the object itself. You find it as the first argument to a *method* (a function that is bound to an instance of an object), whereas you are using standalone function.

The argument to `last_letters()` is the string `'Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan'` when that function is called in `main()`. `last_letters()` does require the argument, but for the aforementioned reasons it should not be named `self`. You could just call it `s` or something descriptive of its value.

Finally the line `last_letters1 = last_letters.split(",")` won't work. You need to call `split()` on a string instance, like this:

```
def last_letters(text):
    names = text.split(",")
    # do something with names...
    # return a list containing the last letter of each name
    return [name[-1] for name in names]
```

Comment: Ohhhh I see. I added that after getting this error (which reoccurs when I don't have `self` there. It reads " `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/main.py", line 2, in main
    last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan')
TypeError: last_letters() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` "

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write code first without functions as this is a small program and once it's running, slowly convert into functions and this helps in understanding  it
without functions.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    last_letters="Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan"
    last_letters1 = last_letters.split(",")
    print(last_letters1)
```

The mistake you did is you're trying to pass `str/word` but you didn't specify that in the function (just give a name so that value you passed will be stored in it)

```
def main():
    last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan')

def last_letters(word):
    last_letters1 = word.split(",")
    print(last_letters1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Exactly your code updated

```
def main():
    last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan')

def last_letters(last_letters):
    last_letters1 = last_letters.split(",")
    print(last_letters1) # to print data
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues:

- You call `main()` in and appropriate way, but as you can tell from the call `main()`, it doesn't need a parameter, so instead of declaring it with `self` as a parameter, it could just be:

```
def main():
    last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan')
```

- Similarly, `last_letters` doesn't need `self` either. Typically, you only see `self` as a parameter in methods on a class, but these are just functions by themselves (and even for a class, the parameter doesn't need to be called `self`, it's just a convention). However, you do need to pass a text to `last_letters`, so it makes sense to define a parameter like `text`:

```
def last_letters(text):
    return text.split(",")
```

- Also note that I changed the code of the function to `return` the result of the split, this ensures that the result is available wherever the function was called, if you do something with it, like capture it in a variable, or print it. Let's print it from `main()`:

```
def main():
    print(last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan'))
```

- Since your function is called `last_letters`, you probably just want the last letters:

```
def last_letters(text):
    return [word[-1] for word in text.split(",")]
```

So, the result is then:

```
def main():
    print(last_letters('Ani,Trevor,Karen,Jasmine,Ryan'))


def last_letters(text):
    return [word[-1] for word in text.split(",")]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the output:

```
['i', 'r', 'n', 'e', 'n']
```

Comment: Uhhh you are a literal magician. Where did you learn all of this?? Do you have any favorite resources you refer to at all? TEACH ME YOUR WAYS. Additionally, instead of separating the last letter by a comma, I'm trying to put them on separate lines. Do you have any idea how I might go about doing this?

Comment: One step at a time, but there's plenty of excellent Python courses and resources out there. The official Python documentation is actually quite well-written and useful, but you need to know the basics to make sense of it. Learning the basics is a matter of working your way through a course of your liking. As for printing them on individual likes, you can just assign that list to a variable `my_list = ...` and then loop over the list `for letter in my_list: print(letter)`

Comment: Would that end up looking like `my_list = last_letters     for letter in my_list: print(letter)` ?

Comment: Give it a try yourself - you'll get it to work; learning how to code is 99% trying stuff and learning by making mistakes.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much ended up figuring it out haha. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I know have a separate problem with only 10 minutes left for me to solve it. At the end of my output, "None" is appearing. And I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of it. I thought using filter() would be okay, but I can't seem to get it to work.